# Find a specific symbol in a string and remove a number of characters to the left of it and to the right in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda column with strings like these:

"[{'node': {'text': '2900₸ размері: 2-3-4-5-6..."

"[{'node': {'text': '3000₸ размері : 1-2-3-4 ..."

I'd like to remove everything to the left of the "₸" symbol except keeping the price i.e. 2900₸ (it may also be a 5 digit number); then remove everything to the right of the "₸" symbol.
The Unicode for ₸ is this: U+20B8

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function to get the price (need to `import regex`)

```
def get_price(s):
    match = re.search("^.+'(\d+₸).*", s)
    if match != None:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        print('No match:', s)
```

Now mapping the above:
`df['price'] = df['old_price'].map(get_price)`

Where *'old_price'* is the column name of the data to reduce.